# Anything Mouse Like Isn't Seen by Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: usb, 13.10, mouse, hardware, bug-reporting

I have a upgraded 13.10 from 13.04 and today this issue of anything that is mouse-like is not seen by Ubuntu.  The only input device that works is my Wacom Tablet and it's pen.  I already checked for updates and have the latest updates for the Ubuntu system.

Here is the lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b209 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 056a:00b8 Wacom Co., Ltd Intuos4 4x6
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

This is issue a bug or how to fix it?  I can't even use the Live USB of Ubuntu 13.10 to fix the issue.

EDIT 1: Seems that Ubuntu isn't seeing the clicks done by a mouse if it's the Wacom tablet.

EDIT 2: I think it's a bug but I need help to report it.

EDIT 3: Based on this question, https://askubuntu.com/questions/394918/mouses-problem?lq=1, it maybe be a bug.   I think it's been confirmed by someone else.  See edit 2, please.

EDIT 4: My trackpad is also broken on Ubuntu 13.04 and Ubuntu 13.10, but I know that is another conformed bug.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this in an answer?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a terminal use this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Comment: I got this: mv: cannot stat ‘/etc/X11/xorg.conf’: No such file or directory

Comment: can you give me the output of: ls /etc/X11

Comment: app-defaults   rgb.txt      Xreset  Xsession.options
core    X       Xreset.d  XvMCConfig
cursors    xinit       Xresources  Xwrapper.config
default-display-manager  xkb       Xsession
fonts    xorg.conf.failsafe  Xsession.d

Comment: Are you currently in failsafe mode?  What happens if you boot normally?

Comment: I'm in normal mode, not safe mode, if that is the same as failsafe.

Comment: Very strange, I guess just reconfigure your server the more traditional way (see the command above)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12127/discussion-between-belkinsa-and-virtualxtc)

Comment: @belkinsa sorry I missed the chat.  Glad it worked.